# Get Woocommerce Subscription Product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to create a form for customers to fill out after they have purchased a subscription and/or when they return to the site and log in. My site has multiple subscription products and I need the form to be conditional based on which product they chose. To see whether they have an active subscription I am using this code:

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription',
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );
```

This only returns the subscription id and status. I need to know which product was purchased with the subscription. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please send more information? how the subscription is saved?

Comment: @CesarHenriqueDamascena I am using the woocommerce subscription plugin

Comment: I don't know this plugin, but maybe one way of doing this, is if you do a `WP_Query` searching for the subscription that you get with the user, and see if you can get the attribute that links the subscription with the product.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Id of a subscription you can get the subscription object :

```
$subscription_obj = wcs_get_subscription($sub_id);
```

wcs_get_subscription is a wrapper for the wc_get_order() method

Then get items of your subscription :

```
$items = $subscription_obj ->get_items();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(['customer_id' => $user_id,'subscriptions_per_page' => -1]);
foreach($subscriptions as $subscription){
  $subscription_id   = $subscription->get_ID();
  $subscription_data = $subscription->get_data();
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Not working in 2023